# Does SSH support *true* pre-shared keys?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption

It is common knowledge that `sshd` running on a publically available machine is a delicious attack vector and thus should be protected as much as possible. Aside from obvious advices like "set `PermitRootLogin` to `no`" and "switch to pubkey authentication", I have found following methods to restrict access to my machine for script kiddies armed with `nmap`:

- Change port to something else than 22. Doesn't really help from aforementioned `nmap`.
- Leave port 22 open, but simply drop everything that comes there and instead accept SSH connections from another port using [this crutch](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:security:ssh). Better than previous method, but it's still no more than a hindrance.
- Set up port knocking. Cumbersome and *still* not perfectly safe, because the "knocking" traffic can be intercepted.

If I were to design a system for remote access to my machine, It would look like this:

1. Generate a random secret.
2. Manually copy it to both machines which should be connected (this can be even done using a flash drive for maximum anal retentiveness).
3. The *very first packet* (i.e. the SSH handshake initiation) that the Client machine sends to the Server is *already* encrypted with this secret.
4. If the Server receives a packet not correctly encrypted with this secret, it just silently closes the TCP connection.

The result is that it is *physically impossible* for an attacker to even find out that an SSH service is running on the Server. In my headcanon *this* is exactly what "pre-shared key" means.

Instead, when I try to search for "ssh with pre-shared key" I get nothing but links to articles on how to migrate from `PasswordAuthentication` to `PubkeyAuthentication`.

Comment: How will the server know which user's key to use? Should all users use the same key? Or should the server test all keys for each "very first packet" until it finds the right one? Or should there be just one user? The current practice is you tell the server who you are and then you authenticate according to what the server knows about the user you claim to be.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski My setup (which, I think, is what most desktop users have) is that (1) I have physical access to both the Server(s) and the Client(s) during configuration stage, and (2) I do not have to add new Client(s) after the configuration stage. So in my case I would be perfectly happy with just one user, and one key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. At protocol level, every standard SSHv2 connection always starts with 1) the protocol version "banner" in plain ASCII, 2) an unencrypted packet that lists all supported ciphers and key-exchange methods.

Starting with step 3 you *could* implement a custom key-exchange method that involves a PSK (ideally *in addition* to the usual dynamic D-H key exchange), but this would require a customized sshd daemon as well as custom clients. No such feature currently exists in OpenSSH, nor PuTTY, nor Bitvise WinSSHD, nor any other SSHv2 implementation that I've played around with so far.

The simplest alternative would be to use a VPN system, as those frequently support PSKs (but more commonly as HMAC keys to protect the initial key-exchange – not as AES keys for encrypting the actual data channel, as that would lose the "forward secrecy" feature). Once you have a VPN service running, you can simply disable direct SSH connections entirely: no one can discover an sshd that is literally not listening anymore.

For example, among the popular ones both WireGuard and OpenVPN support using a pre-shared MAC key to authenticate all connection attempts. As both use UDP for initial negotiation, they simply don't respond *at all* to unverifiable packets, making the service undiscoverable. (Although I believe WireGuard already does so even without PSK mode...) Note that OpenVPN calls this feature "tls-auth" mode – do not confuse it with its "static-key" mode.

It would also be possible to use IPsec AH here – if all you need is a completely static authentication key, it would be possible to configure a SA manually on both ends without needing any dynamic IKE handshake at all, just with an `ip xfrm` command. But it can get annoying.

As yet another alternative, some operating systems support *TCP-level* pre-shared key authentication using either TCP-MD5 (RFC1321) or TCP-AO (RFC5925). This would be easy to hack into SSH software since it only needs a single sockopt, although that's again getting into the territory of custom clients. Also, OS-level support is poor – although TCP-MD5 is still supported as people want to use it with BGP, the support for TCP-AO might be practically nonexistent.

Comment: This is a great answer and exactly what I wanted to hear, please have a green tick good Sir.